# android- requestLocationUpdates() working in ICS but not in android 2.2

Tags: android

When running the application in android 2.2 the GPS is searching for location but doesn't show any location. This application is working perfectly in ICS version. What will be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

This is the complete code :-

```
package com.example.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GPSmap extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    public String mLatLongString = "";
    private String mBest;
    private TextView myLocationText;
    LocationManager mLocManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsmap);
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            Criteria mCriteria = new Criteria();
            mCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            mBest = mLocManager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, true);
            if (mLocManager.isProviderEnabled(mBest)) {
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
            myLocationText.setText("\n\nGPS Tracking: Disabled.");
        }
    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location mLocation) {
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        if (mLocation != null) {
            double mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
            double mLatitudeFormatted = (double) Math.round(mLatitude * 100000) / 100000;
            double mLongitudeFormatted = (double) Math
                    .round(mLongitude * 100000) / 100000;
            mLatLongString = mLatitudeFormatted + ", " + mLongitudeFormatted;
            myLocationText.setText(mLatLongString);
        } else {
            mLatLongString = "\n\nNo Location Found.";
            myLocationText.setText(mLatLongString);
        }
    }

    /** Function to listen to location change */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    protected void onResume() {
        try {
            super.onResume();
            mLocManager.removeUpdates((android.location.LocationListener) this);
            mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(mBest, 60000L, 0.0f, this);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
            myLocationText.setText("\n\nGPS Tracking: Disabled.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code or logcat so that we can get better idea about your problem.

Comment: Where you `are implementing your LocationListener class can you please post the complete code.

Comment: `if (mLocManager.isProviderEnabled(mBest)) { }` complete code ??? If you have it like that leave it out ! Also `mLocManager.removeUpdates((android.location.LocationListener) this);` - why this is not in `onPause()` ? Also why are you catching NPEs ?? This just confuses people and may hide bugs. The NPE is thrown when `mLocManager == null` _only_ ? And by the way you should not initialize `myLocationText` 100 times - this is also noise and confusing. I am in a good mood - otherwise all of these + your formatting would be a -1 ;)

Comment: - ah, I forgot to say - if you want people to concentrate on your problem post only relevant code ! So `if (mLocation != null) { // display location }` instead of the lines you wrote - or does it fail _there_ ?